# Multiple inheritance: cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: c++, c++17, base-class

I have this:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() {};
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    virtual void Draw() = 0;
};

class Derived_1 {
public:
    Derived_1() {};
    void Draw() { std::cout << "Draw()" << std::endl; };
};

class Derived_2 : public Base, public Derived_1 {
public:
    Derived_2() {};
    ~Derived_2() {};        

    //void Draw() { Derived_1::Draw(); }; <<<<<===--- This works well
};

class Derived_3 : public Derived_2 {
public:
    Derived_3() {};
    ~Derived_3() {};        
};

int main()
{
    Base* d = new Derived_3();
    d->Draw();

    return 0;
}
```

I got an error like "pure virtual function "Base::Draw" has no overrider". I think the problem is Derived_2 has two Draw() functions, one of which is virtual. However, I don't know how to fix this without adding wrapper function Draw() in Derived_2 class. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried using the `override ` specifier?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand where to use it

Comment: In `Derived_2 `, right after `void Draw()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you give your `Derived_2` class multiple inheritance (i.e., it derives from both `Base` *and* `Derived_1`) you are saying that it inherits the member functions from **both** base classes.

In this case, that will mean that it has two (different) `Draw` members with the same signatures. Thus, the pure virtual `Draw` function derived from `Base` will **not** be overriden by that derived from `Derived_1`.

In fact, if you use `Derived_3* d = new Derived_3();` in place of your first line of `main()`, as suggested, you will still get the "cannot instatiate abstract class" error, plus another one along the lines of "amibuguous access of Draw()".

Your commented-out line, `void Draw() { Derived_1::Draw(); };` in the `Derived_2` class does two things: (1) It resolves the ambiguity in any later call to `Draw()` from a `Derived_2` class; and (2) it provides a viable override of the pure-virtual `Draw` function of the `Base` class.

Answer (score 2):

The two `Draw` functions are distinct, despite the similarities in name and signature.  They could just as well have two different names.  `Base` and `Derived_1` are unrelated, so `Derived_1`'s `Draw` cannot override `Base`'s.

If `Base::Draw` was not pure virtual, the call to `d->Draw()` in `main` would be ambiguous, because the compiler would not know which draw to call.

The solution is what you have commented out:  provide a `Draw` in `Derived_2` that will call the one in `Derived_1`.  (Not relevant here, but in the alternative where `Base::Draw` is not pure virtual, `Derived_2::Draw` might need to call the `Draw` function in both base classes.)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you defined d as class “Base”, instead of class “Derived_3”, so even though you used the derived_3 constructor the compiler is looking for a definition of draw under “Base.”

Comment: To be more precise, I have an array of many different objects inherited from the base. It seems I can not use "Derived_3* d = new Derived_3()"

Comment: But you can totally create a pointer of the "mother" class and instantiate it as a "son" class. I don't see a problem there

Comment: What’s the specific error for declaring an array of derived_3 using new

Comment: As lenerdv said, since d is declared as base when you call draw it won’t look for derived_1’s draw function, so d must be declared as one of the subclasses, and possibly call draw via :: notation to make the draw’s definition from a specific class.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 functions with the same name and arguments, that is never good. try either changing the name of one of the `Draw()` functions or, if you really want the same name, making `Derived_1` inherit from `Base`

Comment: Derived_1 is library class, I can not change it

Comment: then either change the name of `Base`'s `Draw` or call `Base::Draw` and `Derived_1::Draw` to differentiate between the two. I'm not sure all compilers implement it though.